# error pcap library not found

Tags: linux, gcc, libpcap

i am running Fedora 27 and i am trying to install Reaver 1.4
here is the command.

```
 ./configure
```

and the result.

```
checking for gcc... gcc  
checking whether the C compiler works... yes  
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out  
checking for suffix of executables...   
checking whether we are cross compiling... no  
checking for suffix of object files... o  
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes  
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes  
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed  
checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no  
error: pcap library not found!
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If we only could have some kind of centralised knowledge database where one could type in a request like "pcap library not found" and get a set of automatically collected bits of knowledge related to the problem!

Comment: @n.m. i don't understand where is the problem, i specified that i was trying to install reaver 1.4 on fedora 27 and got the error !

Comment: The **first** result Google returns to me has all required information. (And the second, and the third). Perhaps you should consider changing your Google provider.

Comment: i installed libcap library and still get the error, it feels like libcap is vanished from the system !

Comment: and btw all results your talking about are about ubuntu and debian based , i am using fedora

Comment: i was missing a library all i did is :
  
yum install sqlite-devel

then every thing goes fine. 

Thanks for trying helping me.

Answer (score 1):

For debian based system you'll need the following packages installed:

`sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev`

Then try `./configure` again and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

i was missing a library all i did is :

```
yum install sqlite-devel
```

then every thing goes fine.

Thanks for trying helping me.