# pcap library not found error when trying to install reaver on linux fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I use a Linux Fedora 27 machine and I would like to install reaver-1.4. I have the same problem as described here: [error pcap library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430289/error-pcap-library-not-found) but I tried both commands: `sudo yum install sqlite-devel` and `sudo yum install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev` and nothing works. With the first command nothing seems to change and with second I get the following message:

`No match for argument: sqlite3
No match for argument: libsqlite3-dev
No match for argument: libpcap0.8-dev
Error: Unable to find a match`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't expect packages to be named the same thing in Debian and Fedora, so just swapping in `yum` with the same package names is unlikely to work. Try:

```
sudo yum install libpcap-devel
```

I note that Fedora has version 1.8 instead of version 0.8; hopefully that will not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! (I'm very amateur with linux and its distributions.)